# Solve the integral: $\int \frac{x dx}{{\ln}x+x}$.

Tags: integration

I can't seem to solve this integral nor find a solution to it online; is this integral solvable? If it isn't, is there a way to prove it can't be solved?

Comment: What do you expect? A numerical value for the integral on a given interval $I$, or a primitive of the function $f : x  \mapsto \frac{x}{\ln x + x}$?

Comment: Solvable in terms of a primitive function please.

Comment: It is rare that a function mixing transcendental and algebraic elements in an essential way (like the sum in the denominator here) has an indefinite integral in terms of elementary functions. Mathematica does not know one, so I doubt one exists.

Comment: For some theoretical background on when an antiderivative exists, [Liouville's theorem (differential algebra)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)) is of interest.

Comment: Cute series expansion: $$\int\frac{x}{x + \ln x}dx = \int\frac{1}{1 + \frac{\ln x}{x}}dx = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\int \frac{1}{x}\frac{(\ln x)^n}{x^{n-1}} dx = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\int u^n e^{(1-n)u}du = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(n+1, (n-1)\ln x)}{(1-n)^{n+1}} + C$$ where the substitution was $u = \ln x$ and $\Gamma(a, x)$ is the incomplete Gamma function (that last integral was computed with Wolfram Alpha).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same spirit as @Tob Ernack, let $x=e^t$  to make
$$\int\frac{x}{x + \ln x}\,dx=\int\frac{e^t}{1 + t e^{-t}}\,dt=\int \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n t^n \, e^{-(n-1)t}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\int t^n \, e^{-(n-1)t}\,dt$$
$$I_n=\int t^n \, e^{-(n-1)t}\,dt=-(n-1)^{-(n+1)}\, \Gamma (n+1,(n-1) t)$$ which is what @Tob Ernack wrote.

Another expression could be
$$I_n=\int t^n \, e^{-(n-1)t}\,dt=-t^{n+1}\, E_{-n}((n-1) t)$$ where appears the exponential integral function.

Comment: What is $E_{-n}$ in the last answer?

Comment: @PratikApshinge. Sorry for that. Fixed now.

Comment: Could you please explain the gamma notation you have used; I am unfamiliar with it. Also, when we have an indefinite integral, why can we define the gamma function?